# Writing last n lines from one file to another

Tags: c++, unix

This is the program I have written which copies all the lines from `diskData.dat` file to `24HrDiskData.dat` file. As of now I am copying all the lines from one file to another I wish to copy last **n** lines from `diskData.dat` to `24HrDiskData.dat`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *HrData;
    char tempData[1024];
    int flag = 0;
    ofstream fout;

    fout.open("24HrDiskData.dat", ios::app);    // open file for appending
    assert (!fout.fail());

    if ((HrData = fopen("/home/xvishuk/diskData.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\nFile cannot be opened");
    }
    while (fgets(tempData, 1024, HrData) != NULL) {
        fout << tempData; // write the data to the file
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample pattern of Delimited data**

```
|Sat Mar 26 18:47:57 2016|1|1|182|60.66|3|30|4782|31|68|4|3467750|110|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 19:01:49 2016|1|1|140|46.26|3.03|30|4782|30|68|4|3467764|96|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 19:15:40 2016|1|1|184|61.07|3.01|30|4782|30|68|4|3467777|112|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 19:29:30 2016|1|1|180|59.91|3|30|4782|32|68|4|3467791|98|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 19:43:20 2016|1|1|194|64.61|3|30|4782|32|68|4|3467805|114|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 19:57:17 2016|1|1|170|56.62|3|30|4782|30|68|4|3467818|102|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 20:11:14 2016|1|1|140|46.32|3.02|30|4782|30|68|4|3467832|118|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 20:25:12 2016|1|1|176|58.35|3.02|30|4782|30|68|4|3467846|104|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 20:39:10 2016|1|1|202|66.9|3.02|30|4782|30|68|4|3467859|120|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 20:53:11 2016|1|1|198|65.85|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3467873|106|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 21:07:12 2016|1|1|184|60.97|3.02|30|4782|32|68|4|3467887|92|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 21:21:11 2016|1|1|152|50.28|3.02|30|4782|31|68|4|3467901|108|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 21:35:16 2016|1|1|168|55.77|3.01|30|4782|30|68|4|3467915|94|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 21:49:20 2016|1|1|172|57.03|3.02|30|4782|31|68|4|3467928|112|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 22:03:26 2016|1|1|152|50.56|3.01|30|4782|33|68|4|3467942|98|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 22:17:32 2016|1|1|174|57.86|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3467956|114|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 22:31:38 2016|1|1|156|51.86|3.01|30|4782|30|68|4|3467970|100|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 22:45:44 2016|1|1|202|66.57|3.03|30|4782|30|68|4|3467984|116|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 22:59:55 2016|1|1|188|62.4|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3467998|102|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:14:06 2016|1|1|164|53.95|3.04|30|4782|32|68|4|3468012|118|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:28:17 2016|1|1|168|55.78|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3468026|104|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:42:28 2016|1|1|176|58.33|3.02|30|4782|30|68|4|3468040|120|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:56:39 2016|1|1|170|55.76|3.05|30|4782|30|68|4|3468053|106|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:10:54 2016|1|1|172|56.97|3.02|30|4782|31|68|4|3468067|92|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:25:13 2016|1|1|184|61.23|3.01|30|4782|33|68|4|3468081|108|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:39:26 2016|1|1|188|62.12|3.03|30|4782|31|68|4|3468096|94|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:53:42 2016|1|1|170|56.42|3.01|30|4782|30|68|4|3468110|110|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 01:07:58 2016|1|1|174|57.8|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3468124|96|43.1562|64|
```

**Expected Output**

The last 10 records.

```
|Sat Mar 26 22:45:44 2016|1|1|202|66.57|3.03|30|4782|30|68|4|3467984|116|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 22:59:55 2016|1|1|188|62.4|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3467998|102|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:14:06 2016|1|1|164|53.95|3.04|30|4782|32|68|4|3468012|118|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:28:17 2016|1|1|168|55.78|3.01|30|4782|31|68|4|3468026|104|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:42:28 2016|1|1|176|58.33|3.02|30|4782|30|68|4|3468040|120|43.1562|64|
|Sat Mar 26 23:56:39 2016|1|1|170|55.76|3.05|30|4782|30|68|4|3468053|106|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:10:54 2016|1|1|172|56.97|3.02|30|4782|31|68|4|3468067|92|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:25:13 2016|1|1|184|61.23|3.01|30|4782|33|68|4|3468081|108|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:39:26 2016|1|1|188|62.12|3.03|30|4782|31|68|4|3468096|94|43.1562|64|
|Sun Mar 27 00:53:42 2016|1|1|170|56.42|3.01|30|4782|30|68|4|3468110|110|43.1562|64|
```

Comment: Are you aware that the `tail` program already exists with this exact behavior?

Comment: The expected output as posted is **not** the las 10 records?

Comment: Thanks everyone!! @BenVoigt I agree but I need to do it using a c++ program

Comment: @chqrlie Sorry, I copied the 10 lines randomly from the file

Answer (score 3):

To only write the last `n` lines, you could allocate an array of `n` strings and store the lines into it as you read them, only keeping the last `n` when the array fills up, using modular index to avoid unnecessary copying.

When you reach the end of file, output the lines from the array.

Also avoid mixing C and C++.  Either use `<stdio.h>` or `<iostream>`, but using both at the same time is error prone and inelegant.

Here is a simple implementation in C:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

int main(void) {
    char line[1024];
    char *stash[N] = { NULL };
    int i, j;
    FILE *HrData, *fout;

    if ((fout = fopen("24HrDiskData.dat", "a")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open 24HrDiskData.dat for appending: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if ((HrData = fopen("/home/xvishuk/diskData.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; fgets(line, 1024, HrData) != NULL;) {
        free(stash[i]);
        stash[i] = strdup(line);
        i = (i + 1) % N;
    }
    fclose(HrData);
    for (j = i;;) {
        if (stash[i])
            fputs(stash[i], fout);
        i = (i + 1) % N;
        if (i == j)
            break;
    }
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to store the lines in memory?  Will there be enough memory to store the lines?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews:  Storing the lines in memory is the simplest method.  It works even if the input file is a device or a pipe: seeking into the input would not be possible for those.  Modern computers have enough RAM for most reasonable values of `n` and types of input files.

Comment: A better technique would be to use `std::string` since it allocates dynamically.  You could use `std::getline` with `std::ifstream`.

Comment: For a C++ implementation, I would definitely encourage the use of `std::getline`.

Comment: FYI, the OP has tagged this as C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews:  He originally tagged the question as both C and C++, and he mixes both languages...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chqrlie

Comment: @user1885183: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score.

Answer (score 1):

Two passes.

First pass, count the lines and store their file positions.

Second pass, calculate the line number you want to start copying from.  Look up its file position in the container.  Seek to the file position. Start copying.

**Edit 1: Example code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
  std::string text_line;
  std::vector<std::streampos> file_positions;
  std::ifstream input_file("my_file.txt");
  file_positions.push_back(input_file.tellg());
  while (std::getline(input_file, text_line))
  {
      file_positions.push_back(input_file.tellg());
  }
  // The total lines is file_positions.size().
  // Return the last 13 lines
  const unsigned int total_lines = file_positions.size();
  std::streampos seek_position = 0;
  unsigned int index = 0U;
  if (total_lines > 13U)
  {
      index = total_lines - 13U;
  }
  input_file.clear();
  input_file.seekg(file_positions[index]);
  // Copy text lines to output file...
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2 - More efficient method**
You could maintain a container of *N* text lines as you read through the file.

```
#include <deque>
//...
int main(void)
{
  std::deque<std::string> text_lines(N);
  while (std::getline(input_file, text_line))
  {
     if (text_lines.size() == N)
     {
        text_lines.pop_front();
     }
     text_lines.push_back(text_line);
  }
  // Now copy the text lines from the `std::deque` to the output file.
  //...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use two passes?  Why not do it all in one pass since you have to read the file line by line anyways.

Comment: One, you don't know how many lines are in the file. Secondly, there may not be enough memory to contain the entire file.

Comment: This would not work if the input file is a pipe or a device, or if the input file is modified while seeking back, as is most likely the case of log files such as the one the OP is reading.

Comment: Why do you need memory?  Read in the file line by line and discard them until you find the first line that is within the 24 hour range.  Then copy each line until the end of file into the new file.  The requires only one string worth of data in memory and a single pass.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  I added an example that maintains the last N text lines of the file.

Comment: I don't think either of these will work.  The OP wants all lines from the last 24 hours.  That means the time stamp in each line needs to be read and compared until you find the start of 24 hours back.  I still maintain that my approach in my previous comment is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: My bad, I was understanding that the OP wanted the last N lines, unconditionally.

Comment: @NathanOliver: where do you get this information? *I wish to copy last n lines from diskData.dat to 24HrDiskData.dat* seems unambiguous to me.

Comment: @chqrlie The file name is *24HrDiskData*.  using that and his example it looks like he wants to store just the last records that are within 24 hours. from the end.

Comment: @NathanOliver: that's a wild guess! evidence does not support it: the 12th line from the end has a stamp of `Sat Mar 26 22:31:38`, probably less than 24 hours from the reference date as well. For what it is worth, the posted output is not even the last 10 lines: the very last line is missing.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are correct I wanted to store the records of last 24 hrs in the file.

Comment: @NathanOliver: so you guessed right... I answered the question stated in the post, you can post an answer for the OPs ultimate goal.